# Safe NSArray access

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, memory-management, nsarray, autorelease

I expected `objectAtIndex:` to return a retained and autoreleased object for my use, but my tests with autorelease pools indicate they do not.

This being the case, how do I protect myself against another thread removing an object from an array ***after*** I retrieve its reference using objectAtIndex but ***before*** I have a chance to use or retain that reference?

Comment: Autorelease **never** contributes to thread safety. Not ever.  What BJ Homer said;  you need to use some kind of synchronization primitive to access the array elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronize access to the array, as you should any access to resources shared across threads.